# How to verify genuineness of live bootable USB ubuntu drive?

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, security

I downloaded the Ubuntu iso and did a shasum on it as per the instructions on the website and it matched with the value of the website. Now, the ISO needs to be mounted on a USB drive. There is an application called 'Startup Disk Creator' to do this. Now, my concern is that what if this startup disk creator application itself is compromised? So I need some way of verifying that the bootable USB drive itself is genuine. I tried some methods like given below:

$ stat -c '%s' ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso

2715254784

$ sudo cmp -n 2715254784 ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso /dev/sdb1

ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso /dev/sdb1 differ: byte 1, line 1

but I'm getting a difference in the very first byte. Is there some way of directly authenticating the live bootable usb drive?

Now I understand that there is a md5sum algorithm which can verify this, but this algorithm is considered to be insecure. I want to use sha256.

Comment: Beginning with 20.04, the Desktop installer runs it's own hash (SHASUM) validation during it's boot. This is to let folks know if their .iso download is incomplete or corrupt.

Comment: If you don't trust an application, then verify that there is a problem: Every package (including Startup Disk Creator) is signed and hashed. Apt checks the hash when downloading (indeed it identifies the package *by the hash*), and will terminate with an error is the package is corrupt or tampered with. If you verify that  a package in the Ubuntu repositories has been tampered with, the Ubuntu Security Team will be happy to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to compare SHA256 Sums on the Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop and Server installers:

1. Web Browser: https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/
2. Download the SHA256SUMS file
3. Using any convenient SHA256 method to generate the checksum on your downloaded .iso.

   - In Ubuntu: `sha256sum /path/to/downloaded_file.iso`
   - The `sha256sum` application is included in the `coreutils` package.
4. Compare your result with the SHA256SUMS file.

Comment: I want to do a sha256 sum on the bootable drive itself, not the iso image.